# VirtualHost triggers strange error on Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I have set up an Apache Webserver and I own a domain. I also installed a database and PHP, so I also use PHPMyAdmin as database administration software. Now, I want to put PMA out of the webroot so it is secured.

PMA-directory: C:\wwwSoft\pma

WebRoot: D:\wwwNet

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@something.nl
    DocumentRoot "C:/wwwSoft/pma"
    ServerName db.something.nl
    ServerAlias www.db.something.nl
    ErrorLog "logs/db.something.nl-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/db.something.nl-access.log" common
    <Directory C:/wwwSoft/pma>
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Now, the problem is this error when I visit http://db.something.nl/ : `You don't have permission to access / on this server.`

I believe I set up everything well, but apparently I made mistakes, can someone help me out?